# Bonfire Algorithm Challenge: Where Do I Belong on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hello guys I am currently stuck on this algorithm challenge on FCC. This is what the challenge is all about:

Return the lowest index at which a value (second argument) should be inserted into an array (first argument) once it has been sorted. The returned value should be a number.

For example, `getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1.5)` should return `1` because it is greater than `1` (index 0), but less than `2` (index 1).

Likewise, `getIndexToIns([20,3,5], 19)` should return `2` because once the array has been sorted it will look like `[3,5,20]` and `19` is less than `20` (index 2) and greater than `5` (index 1).

This is my code here:

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    var getIndx;

    var newArr = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a - b);
    });

    for (i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        if (num > newArr[i]) {
            getIndx = newArr.indexOf(newArr[i]);
        }
    }

    return getIndx;
}

getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35);
```

when I ran the code it worked but it isn't passing the test. Guys I need your help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate and check if the actual value is greater then the number. Then retuen the actual index. If no value match, then return the length of the array as new input index.

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    var i;
    arr.sort(function(a, b){
        return a - b;
    });
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > num) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return arr.length;
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35)); // 3
console.log(getIndexToIns([1, 2, 3, 4], 1.5));        // 1
console.log(getIndexToIns([20, 3, 5], 19));           // 2
console.log(getIndexToIns([4, 3, 2, 1], 5));          // 4
```

Alternative version without using a method from the `Array` API

```js
function getIndexToIns(array, value) {
    var i = array.length,
        p = 0;

    while (i--) {
        p += array[i] <= value;
    }
    return p;
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35)); // 3
console.log(getIndexToIns([1, 2, 3, 4], 1.5));        // 1
console.log(getIndexToIns([20, 3, 5], 19));           // 2
console.log(getIndexToIns([4, 3, 2, 1], 5));          // 4
```

Comment: There is no requirement to clone the array

Comment: @Andreas There is no specification not to.  The result is the same, regardless.

Comment: @Nina Thanks a lot  for your assistance. So there is no need to use the indexOf() method for this code.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions proposed so far tend to follow literally the request of the problem: first sort the array, then find the index where to insert the number. That brings you to loop over the array twice. More if you have to clone the array. That is slow, even without considering all the garbage we end up creating ...

Can we do better? I think so.

How about "count how many numbers in the array are less or equal to the number to insert". This achieves the same goal but let's us do it looping only once over the array.

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    return arr.reduce(function (c, x) { return x <= num ? c+1 : c }, 0);
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35)); // 3
console.log(getIndexToIns([20,3,5], 19)); //2 
console.log(getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1.5)); //1
console.log(getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1)); //1
console.log(getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 0)); //0
```

how about that?! twice as fast*, yay!

> * it's probably not *really* twice as fast, if you have to be nitpicky about my claims...

## EDIT

Actually I can do better. That ternary if introduces some branching in the code that bothers me. We could take advantage of javascript weirdness to avoid it

```
arr.reduce(function (c, x) { return c + (x <= num) }, 0)
```

why? because when combined with a numeric operation `true` is converted to 1 and `false` to 0
That removes the extra branching from the code so it's going to be slightly faster than the previous version ... And it would also be easier to unit test, if you care about that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly I think you should look at the previous item from the list:

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    var getIndx = 0;

    var newArr = arr.sort(function (a, b) { return (a - b); });
    for (i = 1; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        if (num >= newArr[i-1]) {
            getIndx = i;
        }
    }

    return getIndx;
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35)); // 3
console.log(getIndexToIns([20,3,5], 19)); //2 
console.log(getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1.5)); //1
console.log(getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1)); //1
console.log(getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 0)); //0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark  why did you initialize the `var i = 1` and not 0?

Comment: Because you cannot go below `0` when using `newArr[i-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for all your assistance. I figured it out and this is the final code here

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {

   var getIndx;

   var newArr = arr.sort(function(a, b){
   return (a - b);
   });

   for (i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {

     if (newArr[i] > num || newArr[i] === num) {

     return i;
      }


   }

   return newArr.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem.

```
const getIndexToIns = (arr, num) => {
    let newArr = arr.concat(num);

    newArr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

    let index = newArr.indexOf(num);

    return index;

}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  let howManySmaller = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i]<num) {
      howManySmaller++;
    }
  }
  return howManySmaller;
}
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).